# Widen write space in output file in python

Tags: python, file, numpy, matrix

I am generating very large matrices (list of lists) in a for loop. I want to place every matrix in a text file, for later access. The problem is that python seems to have limitations to the amount of characters that one can place on a single line.

A matrix that should look like this:

```
[[a,b,c,d,e,f],[g,h,i,j,k]]
```

looks something like

```
[[a,b,c,
d,e,f],
[g,h,i,
j,k]]
```

Of course there are extremely large matrices , so I'd want to expand the number of characters it can put on a single line (infinite? )

This is my code that writes to the file:

```
state_file = open('filename','w')

for item2 in state_lst:
    state_file.write("%s\n" % item2)
    state_file.write("\n")
    state_file.write("\n")

state_file.close()
```

So it's basically writing the elements of a list (in which I have my matrices) in a file.

Comment: Why don't you just use [`savetxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html#numpy.savetxt)?

Comment: Do you need it to be formatted correctly, or do you just want to be able to save the actual matrices?

Comment: If the other solutions are not working for you, you may serialize the matrices using pickle (https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You says

> " I want to place every `matrix` in a text file, for later access"

Yes then you can use `savetext`. as **johnsharpe** mentioned above.

But the problem is that later it will be quite difficult to access these "`matrix`" actually i.e. loading back to a dataform like a `matrix`.

That's why I suggest you to use `pandas` `Dataframe` instead and its has a `save` method as well, then you will be able easily fetch back your data as that was before.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is with the `%s'%item2` formatting.  That uses the default `numpy` array fromatting, which splits the text into multiple lines.  If you want more control over the output use `np.savetxt`, or use what that code does.

Make a long array, and format with `%s` - note the `\n`:

```
In [1417]: item2=np.arange(30.)    
In [1418]: '%s'%item2
Out[1418]: '[  0.   1.   2.   3.   4.   5.   6.   7.   8.   9.  10.  11.  12.  13.  14.\n  15.  16.  17.  18.  19.  20.  21.  22.  23.  24.  25.  26.  27.  28.  29.]'
```

Make a format in the way that `savetxt` does - one format field for each item in the array:

```
In [1419]: fmt=', '.join(['%5.1f']*item2.shape[0])

In [1421]: fmt%tuple(item2)
Out[1421]: '  0.0,   1.0,   2.0,   3.0,   4.0,   5.0,   6.0,   7.0,   8.0,   9.0,  10.0,  11.0,  12.0,  13.0,  14.0,  15.0,  16.0,  17.0,  18.0,  19.0,  20.0,  21.0,  22.0,  23.0,  24.0,  25.0,  26.0,  27.0,  28.0,  29.0'
```

The result is one line without `\n`.  Note the use of `tuple(item2)`.  That's required by `%` formatting.  You can refine the `fmt` to add `[]` or other delimiters.

There are ways of fiddling with the default `numpy` print formatting, but `savetxt` takes this direct approach.